# Windows 7 and GPO - how make this rules?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

First, sorry for this inaccurate post title, but I can't think of better.

My "great" IT teacher gives me commands to execute (all can affect **only one, selected user**)

1. Block installing software, change date and time, access to internet.
2. Require changing password for every 7 days

I know how to make other tasks (that I skipped) like block changing wallpaper. I making it this way:
mmc -> Add snap-in -> Group Policy Editor -> selecting only one user in "Browse" dialog -> activate required templates.

But I can't find any templates about tasks mentioned above.
Also, I can't be sure that tasks is possible to make, last 2h we tried to make it on Windows XP and we proved him that this is impossible to make it this way.

Do I making it wrong way? How make it correct, or may this is impossible?

Comment: 1a) 1b) Remove the user's Administrator access. 1c) [How to Setup Group Policy to Restrict Internet Access](http://www.howtonetworking.com/Internet/restrictie11.htm), [How can I block internet access for a specific user account?](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1440-how-can-i-block-internet-access-for-a-specific-user-account) 2. [Apply or modify password policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc781633(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Ofc, I forgot that user without admin can't install software. But they can't also change time and date? I don't have Win7 now. Setting invalid proxy will block all internet, or only IExplore? I know this solution about password policy and this affects computer, not only user.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974598.aspx

Comment: [AD DS: Fine-Grained Password Policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770394(v=ws.10).aspx) "The Windows Server® 2008 operating system provides organizations with a way to define different password and account lockout policies for different sets of users in a domain."

Comment: [You cannot set the date, time, or time zone on your computer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300022) "By default, only administrators and power users can change the date, time, or time zone."

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - thanks for explaination about date/time, I'll remember it. Previous I think that any normal user can change this.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - about ADDS - I know, so it's like that my IT teacher give us an imposssible task. Thanks!